# Need to group data in Object based on value

Tags: javascript

I am using React/Typescript in my application but need help with basic JavaScript. I am trying to group the data coming from an api call (in this example i'll use mock data) without modifying the actual JSON. I need to group the data based on the 'deviceType' value. So if there are 4 objects, if two are ipad and two are iphone, I need to group those in order. Right now, the mock data is showing Ipad air, then Iphone 6plus, then Ipad air, and then Iphone 6plus again. I need to group these so the new object has the two ipadAir objects first and then the iphone 6plus object coming after. I believe this can be done by making a copy of the old object using spread operator and then modifying it before returning. Here is the data object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "DirectvNowDeviceNotifications": [
            {
                "AccountNumber": "180802190357553",
                "AlertDescription": [
                    {
                        "AlertType": "BUFFERINGERRORS",
                        "AlertCode": "CRITICAL_ISFATAL",
                        "AlertInfo": "ACCOUNT_ALERT",
                        "SkipDismissal": false,
                        "DISMISSAL_EXPIRY_DATE": "",
                        "Content": {
                            "issueTitle": "Buffering Error Detected",
                            "issueDescription": "Buffering Error Detected"
                        },
                        "AlertAdditionalInfo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "reasonCodes",
                                "Value": "CRITICAL_ISFATAL"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "make",
                                "Value": "APPLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceType",
                                "Value": "IPAD AIR"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceID",
                                "Value": "F920BE29-1321-498A-B5D7-7FA84396DE16"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "osName",
                                "Value": "IOS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "ISP",
                                "Value": "TIME WARNER CABLE INTERNET LLC"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Mobile Carrier",
                                "Value": "AT&T"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name":"workflowName",
                                "Value":"CCE_ATTTV_Wifi_Setup"
                            }
                        ],
                        "AdditionalContent": {
                            "longDescription": "You received this error message because the system has captured buffering errors on your device while streaming."
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "AlertType": "BUFFERINGERRORS",
                        "AlertCode": "CRITICAL_FATALV",
                        "AlertInfo": "ACCOUNT_ALERT",
                        "SkipDismissal": false,
                        "DISMISSAL_EXPIRY_DATE": "",
                        "Content": {
                            "issueTitle": "Buffering Error Detected",
                            "issueDescription": "Buffering Error Detected"
                        },
                        "AlertAdditionalInfo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "reasonCodes",
                                "Value": "CRITICAL_FATALVIDEOERROR_CT"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "make",
                                "Value": "APPLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceType",
                                "Value": "IPHONE 6 PLUS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceID",
                                "Value": "F920BE29-1321-498A-B5D7-7FA84396DE16"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "osName",
                                "Value": "IOS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "ISP",
                                "Value": "TIME WARNER CABLE INTERNET LLC"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Mobile Carrier",
                                "Value": "AT&T"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name":"workflowName",
                                "Value":"CCE_DTVN_PLAYER_ERRORS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name":"workflowName",
                                "Value":"CCE_DTVN_PLAYER_ERRORS"
                            }
                        ],
                        "AdditionalContent": {
                            "longDescription": "You received this error message because the system has captured buffering errors on your device while streaming"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "AlertType": "OSUNSUPPORTED",
                        "AlertCode": "N_NOT_SUPPORTED",
                        "AlertInfo": "ACCOUNT_ALERT",
                        "SkipDismissal": false,
                        "DISMISSAL_EXPIRY_DATE": "",
                        "Content": {
                            "issueTitle": "The device you are trying to use with DIRECTV NOW is not supported.",
                            "issueDescription": "The device you are trying to use with DIRECTV NOW is not supported."
                        },
                        "AlertAdditionalInfo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "reasonCodes",
                                "Value": "VSTB_UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "make",
                                "Value": "APPLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceType",
                                "Value": "IPAD AIR"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceID",
                                "Value": "F920BE29-1321-498A-B5D7-7FA84396DE16"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "osName",
                                "Value": "IOS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "ISP",
                                "Value": "TIME WARNER CABLE INTERNET LLC"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Mobile Carrier",
                                "Value": "AT&T"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name":"workflowName",
                                "Value":"CCE_DTVN_PLAYER_ERRORS"
                            }
                        ],
                        "AdditionalContent": {
                            "longDescription": "<a target='_blank' href='https://www.att.com/esupport/article.html#!/directv-now/KM1200941'>Here</a> is a list of supported devices."
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "AlertType": "NA",
                        "AlertCode": "NA",
                        "AlertInfo": "NA",
                        "SkipDismissal": false,
                        "DISMISSAL_EXPIRY_DATE": "",
                        "Content": {
                            "issueTitle": "tell me more title",
                            "issueDescription": "tell me more description"
                        },
                        "AlertAdditionalInfo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "reasonCodes",
                                "Value": "NA"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "make",
                                "Value": "APPLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceType",
                                "Value": "IPHONE 6 PLUS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "deviceID",
                                "Value": "FB2468CF-BF73-4DBC-9600-C61553BB759F"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "osName",
                                "Value": "IOS"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "ISP",
                                "Value": "TIME WARNER CABLE INTERNET LLC"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Mobile Carrier",
                                "Value": "AT&T"
                            }
                        ],
                        "AdditionalContent": {
                            "longDescription": "tell me more long long long description"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "content": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "OK"
    }
}
```

Need objects to be grouped based on device type and return a new object with the proper grouping. Please if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it, I have been struggling with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go through the keys of your object, in the following example I assume that you define this as a javascript object, the result will be two objects each with a key corresponding to the type of device

```
const newGroup = [];
const data = object["data"]["DirectvNowDeviceNotifications"];
(data).forEach((map, index) => {
        Object(map['AlertDescription']).forEach((devices) => {
        if(typeof devices['AlertAdditionalInfo'] !== 'undefined'){
        const deviceType = devices['AlertAdditionalInfo'].find((type) => type.Name ==='deviceType');
        if(typeof deviceType.Value !== 'undefined'){
            if(typeof newGroup[deviceType.Value] === 'undefined'){
            newGroup[deviceType.Value] = [];
          }
            newGroup[deviceType.Value].push(devices);
        }
      }
    })
});
```

example [working](https://jsfiddle.net/gfL529bh/1/)

this code is just an example you should optimize, the idea is to give you an idea of ​​solution

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think I can figure it out now